# HTML uploading problem

Tags: html

i want to upload my first website (it is a simple html file) and when i write on the browser www.examplesite.com it just don't open the site, it opens a raw directory listing where i have to click the "index.html" (which is my site) to get redirected to the real site. How can i fix this? Thanks :)

Comment: where did you upload your site?

Comment: What web server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Do you control the webserver? If so you need to tell the server (ie, Apache, IIS) to use index.html as the "Directory Index". If not ask your ISP to enable it.

Comment: @Mag if it really solve your problem please Accept this answer by clicking the "V" icon.

Answer (score 1):

Webservers can be configured to server different things as the "default" webpage if browsing to a folder - normally, your local, friendly, server administrator should be able to tell you what name(s) to use - index.html is common, but you could try "default.htm" if it's hosted on a Windows server.